# throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name); MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Comapign"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
```

MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Comapign".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (C:\Users\Zakaria5\Desktop\StageTechnique2019\zen-networks-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\missingSchema.js:22:11)

**here is compaign.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var compaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

requestid : {
    type : Number , required : true 
},
requestname : {
    type:String
},

    saltSecret : {
    type : String
    }
});

// Events

compaignSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
bcrypt.hash(this.requestid, salt, (err, hash) => {
this.requestid = hash;
this.saltSecret = salt;
next();
});
});
});


mongoose.model('Compaign',compaignSchema);

}
```

**compaign.controller.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Compaign = mongoose.model('Comapign');
module.exports.register = (req,res,next) =>{
var compaign = new compaign();
compaign.requestid = req.body.requestid;
compaign.requestname = req.body.requestname;
compaign.save((err,doc) =>{

if (!err)
     res.send(doc);

     return next(err); 
});
}
```

**app.js**

```
require('./config/config');
require('./models/db');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const rtsIndex = require('./routes/index.router');

var app = express();

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api',rtsIndex);


// start server 
app.listen(process.env.PORT,() => console.log(`Server started at port : ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

Comment: It's a spelling error... `Comapign` is not `Compaign`. Which is also not the english word "Campaign" if that's the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your compaign model in  compaign.model.js like this:

```
const Compaign = mongoose.model('Compaign ',compaignSchema);
exports.Compaign = Compaign;
```

And import and use it in your controller like this:

```
const {Compaign } = require("./compaign.model");

module.exports.register = (req, res, next) => {

  const { requestid, requestname } = req.body;

  var compaign = new Compaign ({
    requestid,
    requestname
  });

  compaign.save((err, doc) => {

    if (!err)
      res.send(doc);

    return next(err);
  });
}
```

If your controller is inside the controllers folder, and the model is in the models folder, your should import your model to the controller like this:

```
const {Compaign } = require("../models/compaign.model");
```

Comment: I also have to fix this path ````./Compaign.model ```` it generates an error while runing my server !! although I have tried  ````./models/Compaign.model```` and I have tried also  ````./models/compaign.model````  in vain !! It displays : Cna't find module !

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal please check your filename and model name

Comment: Maybe ../models/compaign.model is needed. I dont know your project file structure.

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal  can you provide the folder structure of your app so that I can try to resolve module importing.

Comment: Inside my Folder called ````models```` My file name is ````compaign.models.js````  And Im working on  ````compaign.controller.js```` . Thus ,  the right thing is to make ````./compaign.model```` becauz  ````compaign.controller.js```` file is in ````contorllers```` Folder

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal  Did you try like this? ../models/compaign.model

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal  I edited answer, according to your folder structure, please have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
mongoose.model('Compaign',compaignSchema);
```

and when you call it, you do:

```
const Compaign = mongoose.model('Comapign');
```

Compaign != Comapign